# Why are date values input in a SQL query not equivalent to the same date value in the excel worksheet?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ado

Code is below:

```
If Total_rows_NMRDTRSummary > 1 Then
Dim objConnection As Variant
Dim objRecordset As Variant
Dim connectionString As String
    Const adOpenStatic = 3
    Const adLockOptimistic = 3
    Const adCmdText = &H1

    Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set objRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=C:\Users\Sun-Lap\Desktop\Payroll Computations (Template).xlsm; Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0; HDR=YES"";"
    objConnection.Open connectionString

    For i = 2 To Total_rows_NMRDTRSummary
        objRecordset.Open "Select * FROM [N-MR Data$] WHERE Person = '" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("N-MR DTR Summary").Cells(i, 1) & "' AND Date = " & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("N-MR DTR Summary").Cells(i, 2), objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

        Do Until objRecordset.EOF
            Debug.Print objRecordset.Fields.Item("Date"), _
                objRecordset.Fields.Item("Person")
            objRecordset.MoveNext
        Loop

        objRecordset.Close
    Next i
End If
```

The issue is the `objRecordset.EOF` is `True` for the whole `For-next` loop meaning that there are no matches found in the `N-MR Data` worksheet that matches a pair in `N-MR DTR Summary`. This is odd because the same `Person` and `Date` columns in `N-MR DTR Summary` is derived from `N-MR Data` worksheet. And upon checking, both are dates are have a numeric equivalent in Excel.

The portion with the issue is the `Recordset` object:

```
objRecordset.Open "Select * FROM [N-MR Data$] WHERE Person = '" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("N-MR DTR Summary").Cells(i, 1) & "' AND Date = " & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("N-MR DTR Summary").Cells(i, 2), objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
```

Hard coding the date into a numeric equivalent will have a match and would work correctly, but if it was in the date format (like the previous example), it would not return any matches. The below code will work as expected:

```
objRecordset.Open "Select * FROM [N-MR Data$] WHERE Person = '" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("N-MR DTR Summary").Cells(i, 1) & "' AND Date = 43594", objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
```

Answer (score 0):

`43594` is NOT a date.  It is a number.  Excel happens to interpret this number as the number of days since 1899-12-31.

Databases generally do not store dates this way.  In fact, there is no standard mechanism for the internal storage of dates across different systems.

The correct way to pass a date constant into a query is to use a typed parameter and to assign that parameter an appropriate date value.

A secondary way is to construct a date, preferably as a YYYYMMDD or YYYY-MM-DD string.

However, numbers are not dates and should not be treated as such.

Comment: My excel column displays each date cell under it in the format of `MM/DD/YY` if I feed this into the SQL query it will not work with the SQL query string. I also tried formats like the `Long Date` which is something like `Thursday, May 09, 2019` but same issue applies. Does it mean I have to convert the excel date into a `YYYY-MM-DD` string with a dash before feeding it into the sql query statement?

Comment: @Martin . . . Pass it in as a parameter, typed as a date.